# How to disable chartjs legendclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I would like to disable chart.js Spider chart legend click because when I click on the legend the data series is hiding the associated set of values as shown in the below images.

[image]

[image]

My requirement is that I do not want to disable the dataset. I have tried the preventDefault(); on the chart click but it is not working.

My code sample is attached below. Please check..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Radar Chart</title>
    <script src="../dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:75%">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    };
    var randomColorFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    };
    var randomColor = function(opacity) {
        return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
    };

    var config = {
        type: 'radar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            },  {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,120,0,0.5)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                hoverPointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            },]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation()
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: ''
            },
            scale: {
              reverse: false,
              gridLines: {
                color: ['black']
              },
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);
    };





    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try set a handler : onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation() at canvas

Comment: Had the same problem. Just remove the click, touch handlers in options.

Comment: @Nitin Can you expand on that? Not having the `onClick` handler will mean it will return to the default behaviour? This is how ive implemented it in my own projects but is there a different option your referring to?

Comment: @ste2425 will post the exact changes i made in 3 hrs (at work right now). There is an option where you can define which events are active.

Comment: @ste2425 you are right, that is the way to do it. My current solution is similar to that by xnakos. Another option would be to implement your own legend and hide the native legend. References:

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2437

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.legend.js#L16-L26

To implement your own legend and hide the native chartjs legend: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2565

Answer (score 79, accepted):

According to the docs there is a `onClick` handler for the legend exposing the event object. If you `stopPropagation` it stops the data series hiding:

```
        let chart = new Chart(elem.find('canvas')[0], {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: [],
                    datasets: []
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation()
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

The above is ES6, if your not using a supported browser below is the older ES5 equivilant.

```
legend: {
    onClick: function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Chartjs must register its own click event after the `legend.onClick` which is why this stop it executing.

[docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html)

Comment: Can you then post your code as to how your implementing the chart. The above code does work, I'm using it in my project with the latest Chart.Js. Just saying 'not working' doesn't offer much info as to what isn't working. You could have missed a comma or you could be on a version with a different interface etc. On a side note that code is ES6 your browsers support that right?

Comment: Looking at your posted code i cant see any obvious issues. I'm using the ES6 arrow function syntax which not all browsers (IE) support yet. You could try the old ES5 syntax `onClick: function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); }`. I updated my answer in case.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Now it is fine. Is there any way to highlight the data set on legend click like Google chart?

Answer (score 21):

Also, you can use `null` or any value which is evaluated `false` to disable click event on all legend.

```
options: {
    legend: {
        onClick: null
    }
}
```

Note: Ignore click event by `onClick` on following code in Chart.js ( https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/6bea15e7cf89003e3a5945a20cf1d2cc5096728e/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js#L481 )

Comment: simpler solution. nice.

Comment: options: {
     plugins : {
                legend: {
                    onClick: function(event, legendItem) {}
                }
            }
}

Answer (score 20):

At the time of writing (Chart.js v3.5.1), the correct answer is

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      onClick: null
    }  
  }
}
```

As per Natan Almeida de Lima's comment above. Adding it as an answer since I didn't see it as a one-line comment which I only found after figuring it out for myself.

Comment: This one worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me on newest version.

Comment: It gives the error, Type 'null' is not assignable to type '((this: LegendElement<"bar" | "line">, e: ChartEvent, legendItem: LegendItem, legend: LegendElement<"bar" | "line">) => void) | undefined'.ts(2322). Could you please help me with it

Comment: It work on Chrome with Chart.js v3.8.0, unable to set it from default settings : // not work  : Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick = null; (or function(){...} )

Answer (score 7):

To override the default behavior of clicking on a legend item, that is showing/hiding the associated dataset in the chart, you may use the following option (shown inside `options` for clarity):

```
options: {
    legend: {
        onClick: function(event, legendItem) {}
    }
}
```

This is the way to override the default behavior, that is by supplying a function with the same arguments. According to your requirements, this function should have an empty body (and, thus, return immediately), since absolutely nothing should happen when clicking on a legend item. Look for `legend.onClick` in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/). While it currently appears under only two chart types, this option should work for all chart types.

Comment: Oh so the existence of the handler overwrites the default behavior? Not the preventDefault itself?

Comment: @ste2425 Explicitly defining an option will override its default value (in our case the default value is a function (which will be called on click) that hides or shows the dataset (if the dataset is shown or hidden respectively at the time of the call / at the time of the click)). That is the way in general with Chart.js. Change the callbacks by supplying alternative ones (e.g. for tooltips). I do not think that you need to mess with event propagation for most cases.

Comment: And just so you know... if you want to call the original (global default) handler from your override, you need to use .call(this, event, legendItem), which is not what the documentation says but is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) version 4.4.0, you can use the following solution:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      onClick: (e) => e.native.stopPropagation()
    }  
  }
}
```

Additional information: The Event triggered by `onClick` (in the example: `e`) has the following type: [ChartEvent](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/ChartEvent.html).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add properties *`legendItemClick`* to override default action. It's work good for pie chart

```
legendItemClick: function(e){
                    console.log("Clicked an item with text: " + e.text);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/events/legenditemclick

Comment: doesn't answers the question at all